# Why doesn't std::ratio have a value member?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I'm curious as to the reasoning behind why `std::ratio` only exposes the `num` and `den` values, and not some `value` member which would represent the rational value of the ratio, possibly of the form

`static constexpr double value = num / den;`

I imagine it could be because

- They might not have wanted to lock in double (or any one particular) precision
- The operation is trivial to perform in user code
- It might require a nasty (unsafe?) cast

but I'm curious if there are other good reasons for the lack of a single value member in the standard?

*ASSIDE:*

There's a practical application to this for me, because I'm looking to implement a more strongly typed version of `std::ratio` for a [strongly-typed unit library](https://github.com/nholthaus/units) that I've been working on, for which I think something like the following would make sense (assuming I'm not missing some understanding about `std::ratio` and const-ness)

```
template<typename UnitType, std::intmax_t Num, std::intmax_t Denom = 1>
struct unit_ratio : private std::ratio<Num, Denom>
{
    static const UnitType value() { return UnitType((double)num / den);
};
```

In this case, obviously performing `num / den` in user code is not the same thing as being returned a `UnitType` which contains the value `num / den`, but I'm somewhat wary that it's a bad idea since `std::ratio` doesn't do something similar.

Comment: Isn't it because the floating point number may not actually represent the ration?

Comment: @NathanOliver it seems to me that it would represent it as well as `double val = (double)myRatio::num / myRatio::den` which is what most people are going to do with it in their code. I typically use `ratio` to get around the fact that templates can't take non-integral non-type members.

Comment: A double is not really a *rational* value, its an approximation of a *real* value. Rational numbers are whole numbered ratios.

Comment: You want to have a single return type (value type)  of multiple possible types - but -  the standard defines none.

Comment: @Galik, understood, but in many scenarios (like mine), `std::ratio` is being used as an approximation of an approximation of a real value, and not actually as an intentionally rational value. That said I can see why it wouldn't be standard-worthy.

Comment: If someone converts a ratio to a `double` for any reason other than a debugging display purpose, they have screwed up.  Helping the end user screw up is not something the standard should be doing.  `ratio` is not meant to replace `double` (thank god!) in templates, it is to let you put rational numbers into templates.  These are not the same thing.  `double`s are poor approximations of real values, worse approximations of rational values, and generally only really good when you mainly care about speed and for it to mostly work sometimes.

Comment: @Galik: Every double is in fact a rational value, with a denominator that's a power of two. The real problem is that it doesn't work the other way around - not every rational has a denominator that's a power of two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe because there is no floating point nor double that can be *exactly* equal to a ratio as simple a `1/3` or `1/5` . Only the ratio obtained by linear combinations of 1/2<sup>n</sup> using integer coefficients have exact [IEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) floating point representations.

You must remember that `std::ratio` is for *rational* numbers, that is numbers of the form num/den where num and den are both integral values.

So IMHO you can define a *float_approx* if you like, but do not call it value unless you really want to face ugly cases where two different ratios would still share same *value*.

Comment: "par combinations" should be replaced with "sums" (and only some such sums).

Comment: I think the consensus here is that I'm abusing ratio a little bit, and you're right that the crux of the problem seems to be that I need a more semantically correct name for the struct.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus Really, there are very very few units (are there *any?* in todays world?) for which there isn't a rational ratio between them.  Going to double for units is a bad plan even if you aren't using `ratio`.

Comment: @Yakk, I'm only using rational values (ratios) for the _conversions_, but the `unit_ratio` class was intended to store _values_ of units for other classes which need to define them at compile-time (as opposed to storing them in std::ratio which doesn't have the unit type associated with it. The value stored by a unit type can't be limited to integral or rational values.

Comment: @nico why can't it?  What unit is not an integer ratio or whatever baseline?  I will admit that you may need bignum, but units in physics are rational multipliers of each other.

Comment: @Yakk, I agree that you're right about what you are saying, but I'm not trying to solve a unit conversion problem, I've already done that, and I did only use rational ratios. I'm trying to store arbitrary values as types at compile time to support compile time arithmetic on them as part of a larger coordinate-conversion library. Those values are fine to work with as doubles, because the ratios I used for them either were already approximations, or had sufficient precision for what I was doing.

Comment: Just musing: `using pi = std::ratio<2646693125139304345, 842468587426513207>;` :-)

Comment: @HowardHinnant I actually ended up representing pi as a `std::ratio` scale factor which gets multiplied to the conversion at the end if necessary. Using big numbers in the conversion ratios led to a lot of overflow situations.

Comment: @HowardHinnant, you're trying too hard :-) `using pi = std::ratio<22, 7>;` or if you really insist  `using pi = std::ratio<355, 113>;`